# Как расположить элементы таким образом?

Tags: html, css

Как расположить элементы таким образом, чтобы блок .inverted с перевернутым текстом прилегал к краю .wrapper-а и был наравне с логотипом и чтобы второй блок .features сдвинулся к середине. В родительском блоке .content я задал свойство display: flex и хотел выровнять содержимое блока по краям, но почему-то перевернутая надпись не прилегает к левому краю и следовательно при маленьком разрешении экрана она будет ездить туда сюда.

Сам сайт ilyin1ib.beget.tech

```css
.about_us {
    background: url(../img/about_us.jpg) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 120px 0;
    line-height: 1.3;
}


.about_us .wrapper .content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


.inverted {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}


.pink {
    background-color: #E67AC4;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 10px;
}


.features {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    max-width: 1015px;
    width: 100%;
}


.features h4 {
    font-size: 28px;
    width: 626px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
   
}


.features-block {
    display:  flex;
    justify-content:  space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}


.quantity_block {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}


.quantity_numbers {
    font-size: 95px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 90px;
}


.quantity_numbers.one {
    color: #E78E76;
}


.quantity_numbers.two {
    color: #7DEBDF;
}


.quantity_numbers.three {
    color: #4AB5FF;
}


.features-block .desc {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<section id="about_us" class="about_us">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="inverted">
                        <h2>Веб-студия Inter-web – это<br>возможность <span class="pink">заявить о себе</span></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="features">
                        <h4>Мы всегда отслеживаем новые тенденции и на их основе предлагаем уникальные предложения. </h4>
                        <div class="features-block">
                            <div class="quantity_block">
                                <span class="quantity_numbers one">10</span>
                                <span>лет на рынке</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <p>Агентство “Inter-web” существует на рынке более *n* лет. За все время работы мы успели построить доверительные отношения со всеми клиентами и показать весь наш профессионализм в работе.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="features-block">
                            <div class="quantity_block">
                                <span class="quantity_numbers two">75</span>
                                <span class="state">специалистов в<br>штате</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <p>У нас идет строгий отбор сотрудников фирмы. В агентстве “Inter-web” работают исключительно профессионалы своего дела.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="features-block">
                            <div class="quantity_block">
                                <span class="quantity_numbers three">150</span>
                                <span>выполненных<br>проектов</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <p>За плечами более *количество* успешно сделанных и работающих сайтов.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </section>
```

Как у меня
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как надо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/RwVwwoL

Answer (score 0):

У блока `.inverted` удалите правило `width: 100%`

Comment: Убрал, но тогда обрезается надпись и она переносится на третью строчку и плюс при уменьшении экрана она не прилегает к левому краю